# PeriodicSync no funciona en Android Kitkat y Lollipop

Tags: java, android

Mi Sync Adapter funciona correctamente la **Sincronización periódica** con Android Marshmallow, pero no funciona con KitKat y Lollipop. En estas dos versiones, que no funciona la sincronización periódica, si funciona en forma manual. He buscado soluciones y no he encontrado nada en la web. El código, en el que creo que está el inconveniente es el siguiente:

```
if (newAccount != null) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

            SyncRequest request = new SyncRequest.Builder()
                    .syncPeriodic(SYNC_INTERVAL, SYNC_FLEXTIME)
                    .setSyncAdapter(newAccount, authority)
                    .setExtras(new Bundle())
                    .build();

            ContentResolver.requestSync(request);
        } else {
            ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(newAccount, authority, new Bundle(), SYNC_INTERVAL);
        }
    }
```

Saludos y gracias por la atención.

Comment: ¿Alguna solución?